# R: Improving Nested ifelse Statements & Multiple Patterns

Tags: r, if-statement, pattern-matching, grepl

I am continuing to work on some data cleaning practice with some animal shelter data. My goal here is to shrink down the number of breed categories.

I am using each breed category as a **partial** pattern match against the `outgoing$Single.Breed` data frame column. So, there are cases where the breed will just be `Chihuahua`, but it may also be `Long Hair Chihuahua`. (Hence, my use of `grepl`.) Thus, anything containing a breed category would be represented in a different column by said category. Furthermore, I also need to add the ***cat*** breed categories...making for an even messier bunch of code.

The code below is my *"solution"*, but it's quite clunky. Is there a better, slicker and/or more efficient way to accomplish this?

```
BreedCategories <- ifelse(outgoing$New.Type == "Dog",
           ifelse(grepl("Chihuahua",outgoing$Single.Breed, ignore.case = TRUE), "Chihuahua",
           ifelse(grepl("Pit Bull",outgoing$Single.Breed, ignore.case = TRUE), "Pit Bull",
           ifelse(grepl("Terrier",outgoing$Single.Breed, ignore.case = TRUE), "Terrier",
           ifelse(grepl("Shepherd",outgoing$Single.Breed, ignore.case = TRUE), "Shepherd",
           ifelse(grepl("Poodle",outgoing$Single.Breed, ignore.case = TRUE), "Poodle",
           ifelse(grepl("Labrador|Retriever",outgoing$Single.Breed, ignore.case = TRUE),"Labrador",
           "Other")))))),"Cat")
```

Comment: You need to include enough data for your question to be [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but check out `dplyr::case_when`.

Comment: If all you are trying to do it check if a breed name is listed your don't need the `ifelse`, again a reproducible example plus your desired output would be ideal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a data.frame that maps between the regular expression and what the breed is

```
map <- data.frame(
    pattern=c(
        "Chihuahua", "Pit Bull", "Terrier", "Shepherd",
        "Poodle", "Labrador|Retriever", "Other"),
    isa=c(
        "Chihuahua", "Pit Bull", "Terrier", "Shepherd",
        "Poodle", "Labrador", "Other"),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and some data

```
outgoing <- data.frame(Single.Breed=c(map$isa, "Pit Bull Poodle", "Pug"),
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

For the program, use `vapply()` and `grepl()` to match each pattern to the data; the use of `grepl()` means that the result is a matrix, with rows corresponding to each entry

```
isa <- vapply(map$pattern, grepl, logical(nrow(outgoing)), outgoing$Single.Breed)
if (any(rowSums(isa) > 1))
    warning("ambiguous breeds: ", outgoing$Single.Breed[rowSums(isa) != 1])
```

Use `max.col()` to visit each row and retrieve the best (last) match (which happens to be 'Other' if there are no matches).

```
outgoing$BreedCategory <- map$isa[max.col(isa, "last")]
```

Here's the result

```
> isa <- vapply(map$pattern, grepl, logical(nrow(outgoing)), outgoing$Single.Breed)
> if (any(rowSums(isa) > 1))
+     warning("ambiguous breeds: ", outgoing$Single.Breed[rowSums(isa) != 1])
Warning message:
ambiguous breeds: Pit Bull Poodle 
> outgoing$BreedCategory <- map$isa[max.col(isa, "last")]
> outgoing
     Single.Breed BreedCategory
1       Chihuahua     Chihuahua
2        Pit Bull      Pit Bull
3         Terrier       Terrier
4        Shepherd      Shepherd
5          Poodle        Poodle
6        Labrador      Labrador
7           Other         Other
8 Pit Bull Poodle        Poodle
9             Pug         Other
```

I guess the approach is appealing because it more clearly separates the 'data' (regex and input breeds) from the 'program' (`grepl()` and `max.col()`).

The handling of 'Other' seems a little fragile -- what if you forget that it is supposed to be the last element of `map`? One possibility is to create an indicator variable that tests the row sums of isa, and uses this to conditionally assign the breed

```
test = rowSums(isa)
outgoing$BreedCategory[test == 0] = "Other"
outgoing$BreedCategory[test == 1] = map$isa[max.col(isa)][test == 1]
outgoing$BreedCategory[test > 1] = "Mixed"
```

The above is not very space efficient (the matrix transforms your length n data to an n x # of regex matrix), but seems likely to get the job done for say 1M input rows.

`dplyr::case_when()` seems to require that you write many `grepl()` statements, which is error prone.

Comment: I like this - you could also use `map$isa[max.col(isa, "first")]` to avoid the `apply` statement.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks! I'll admit to not know about `max.col()` (odd that there isn't a `max.row()`).

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful and got the job done! This'll definitely be another clever strategy that I will add to my R toolbox for future use! I agree that 'Other' is rather fragile. The indicator variable is a nice way to solve it, disregarding the space inefficiency. Fortunately, my data set isn't massively huge, so that variable is definitely an option if necessary.